# List of persons with fields from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I'm a newbie with relational databases. My client asked for a list of clients with different fields by default. But in the schema are like 8 different tables and I need to make the list with fields for each one.

I was thinking of implementing a query like this one.

```
SELECT name, surname, country_of_birth, nationality, email 
from clients,
     client_documents as documents,
     client_addresses as address
```

There are duplicate fields, but I don't know how to use the same `uuid_client` with it's the foreign key in each table.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?'

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Btw, tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: What exactly is missing with the current query?

Comment: When several tables are involved, it's good programming practice to qualify all columns, e.g. `clients.name` instead of just `name`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `join` and shorter table `aliases` so it will be easier for you to include its `columns`.

```
select t1.name
    , t1.surname
    , t1.country_of_birth
    , t1.nationality
    , t1.email 
    , t2.documents
    , t3.city
from clients t1
inner join client_documents t2 on t1.uuid_client = t2.uuid_client
inner join client_addresses t3 on t1.uuid_client = t3.uuid_client
```

Comment: Teach TS to chose table aliases that makes sense, like `c` for `clients` etc.

Comment: well, i'm more comfortable using this than a, b, c, let say orders, order details, order summary, so will need additional letter to abbreviate, unlike t1, t2, t3, i know my first table is t1, second join table is t2..etc...'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, surname, country_of_birth, nationality, email 
from clients, client_documents as documents, client_addresses as address
```

From the query above it seems you need to join the tables. But you didn't mention any of the fields from the remaining tables. So, if you have any common fields in these tables it is possible to use `joins`

Or Else you can try using `UNION` too.
Please Elaborate your question. So that I can answer it properly

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve it is using `JOIN`.
For example :

```
SELECT clients.name, clients.surname, address.country_of_birth, clients.nationality, clients.email 
FROM clients clients 
LEFT JOIN client_documents AS documents on clients.id = documents.client_id
LEFT JOIN client_addresses AS address on clients.id = address.client_id
```

I suggest LEFT JOIN for this case, because you cannot see clients do not have   address or documentation info if we use (INNER) JOIN. So we used LEFT join, but as I said the choice depends on your scenario.